# parse a url in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, url

I want to create a HTTP link from db info. such as ip and port number, somehow i tried this but keep getting a error cant parse  and port hope any one can help me out

```
 @app.route('/link_test/<string:id>')
 @is_logged_in
 def link_test(id):
     #Create cursor
     cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
     #get item by itemno
     result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM testlist WHERE id = %s", [id])
     doc = cur.fetchone()

        )
     doc = {"id": test[0], "rdno": test[1], "ipno": test[2], "port": test[3]}
     cur.close()
     ipno = test['ipno']
     port = test['port']
     url_uptime = 'https://<string:ipno>:<string:port>/stats/uptime/'  

     return render_template('link_test.html', uptime=json.loads(r_uptime))
```

Comment: I think you're getting an error because of the random `) ` character, and `test`;is never defined. And you're not parsing anything. Looks like you're trying to format a URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<string:ipno>:<string:port>` is a Flask path, not something to be literally used as a URL

If you wanted to create this string, it's called formatting, not parsing

```
ipno = doc['ipno']
port = doc['port']
url_uptime = 'https://{}:{}/stats/uptime/'.format(ipno, port)
r_uptime = requests.get(url_uptime, verify=False).content
```

You'll also want to define `test` somewhere before `doc` is created

Comment: Thanks mate great :)

Comment: what if the url is down how to say the value is "down"

Comment: Move `requests.get` response to its own variable, then check out the status code of that. If it's okay, then get the content, else set it to `"down"`

Comment: What if i use status_code: 

    if url_uptime.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
          r_uptime = _session.get(url_uptime).content
    else:
        r_uptime = "down"

Answer (score 0):

getVars1 = doc[2]

url='/stats/uptime/'
url_uptime = ('https://'+getVars1+url)

great thanks mate